# How to check the number of arguments passed with a Ruby Script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how to get the number of arguments pass with a ruby script. So far everything I searched for has been to functions.

I execute my script like this: `ruby script.rb Arg1 Arg2 Arg3`

Now I want to get the number of arguments, in this case it is 3. How can I do so?

I am using ruby1.9.3

**EDIT:** I want my code to look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# check number of arguments passed

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 8):

`ARGV` contains all the arguments passed to the script, `ARGV.length` is the number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks. +1 and I will accept the answer once stackoverflow will let me

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `ARGV` array. It's just like any other array, but it's populated with a list of command line arguments passed.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html